# Find solution of under-determined system that is close to a starting point

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

Can I provide a starting point y to one of the eigen's solver for Ax = b?

I want to get an exact solution x that is close to the starting point y.

When would solving Ax = b with Newton's method (without line search) not converge?

Thanks.

Comment: How large is `A`? Is it dense or sparse?

Comment: dense, quite small like 10 x 15.

Comment: Newton's method is for non-linear systems. Just use a full pivoting QR decomposition, or if that is not sufficient a singular value decomposition. You will get a solution close to the origin.

Comment: And to get a solution closest to a given `y`, just translate your problem to make `y` the origin before calling CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition or SVD.

Comment: Sorry, which vectors should I get from the QR, SVD, or CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition? I guess a solution close to the origin means a vector in the null space of A. But eigen's QR/SVD seems to not have a kernel method. Only FullPivLU has that. I want an x that is close to y.

Comment: If you substitute `x=y+u`, (for a given initial `y`) you solve the system `A*(y+u)=b` which is equivalent to `A*u = b-A*y` for `u` with a minimum norm solution of `u` and `(A*u - (b-A*y))` and calculate `x = y+u` afterwards.

Comment: The least square solution x of Ax = b minimize norm of (Ax - b) instead of norm of x. Solving Au = b - Ay for a least square solution u minimize norm of [Au - (b - Ay)] instead of norm of u. So, I think that won't minimize u, which is x - y and the distance between vector x and y.

Comment: Found a solution with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: You missed the fact that A is not full rank, and so solving for `Ax=b` using SVD will find, among the subspace of solution, the one that minimizes the norm of x. Same goes for `Au = b - Ay`

Comment: Sorry. I thought the least square solution minimizes square norm of `Ax - b`,  as explained at https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html That least square solution does not necessarily minimize the norm of `x`. If we just minimize norm of `x` without any constraint, `x` would be the zero vector. Given a `y`, that least square solution also doesn't minimize norm of `x - y` subjected to the constraint `Ax = b`.

Comment: Does the least square solution given by SVD have any additional property other than just being the least square solution of `Ax = b`?

Comment: @chtz Thanks for explaining the point about Newton's method and non-linear system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve Ax = b for a solution that minimize L2 norm of x - y.

Given a y, that means minimizing L2 norm of x - y, subjected to the constraint Ax = b.

By Lagrange multiplier I get the following block matrix equation.

The vector u are one half of the lagrange multipliers.

```
/ A    0  \  / x \     / b \
|         |  |   |  =  |   |
\ I   A^T /  \ u /     \ y /
```

Probably not the fastest way.